# I am building a MERN app Where can I store Images that would allow my app private access other than in the app itself?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, web-hosting, mern

I am building a MERN app which has images of products but also images of personal information uploaded from the user. Originally I was gonna host it on Google so I thought google storage was a good option but I was recently informed that my app would not be able to consistently access the images from a private setting. While I have no problem with the images of the products being public, I need the personal information to be private. I would like to host and store the images in one place if possible. I thought about storing the personal images in the DB but I thought that as the number of users grow it might slow the app down. Would appreciate and insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make one of your buckets public and a different one private!

**For the public bucket.** Grant the special user `allUsers`, the role `Object viewer`. Like that, any unauthenticated user will be able to view and download the file.

The role `object admin` (that allows you to read, write and delete the object) MUST not be granted on allUsers, but only to admin, like you.

**For the private bucket.** Grant the special user `allUsers`, the role `roles/storage.objectCreator` role (take a look at [IAM roles for Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)) :

> Allows users to create objects. Does not give permission to view,
> delete, or overwrite objects.